# Why my variable 'extra' is modified, while I am changing a copy of it.(Specific, not a general query)

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, variables

I am trying to solve  Bear and Steady Gene problem in HackerRank.
I have an int array variable named extra, which I copy in extra_temp and do all modifications in this new variable, but somehow, original variable 'extra' is modified. I know it is strange but to be honest, I have spent hours to understand why this is happening but I can not find the reason for this. Here is my code

```
    public static int subFinder(int[] extra, char[] S, int N)
    {

    List<Integer> opt=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int start=0;
    int end=0;
    int r=1;
    int[] extra_tmp=new int[4];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        extra_tmp=extra;
        //System.out.println(extra[0]);
        //System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(extra[1]);
        //System.out.println("");
        //System.out.println(extra[2]);
        //System.out.println("");
        //System.out.println(extra[3]);
        //System.out.println("Hello");
        int count=0;

        if(extra_tmp[S[i]-97]>0)
        {
            start=i;
            extra_tmp[S[i]-97]--;
            for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
            {  
                if(extra_tmp[S[j]-97]>0)
                {
                    extra_tmp[S[j]-97]--;
                    end=j;
                }
            }

                System.out.println("Hello");
                    opt.add(end-start+1);
                    i=i+2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(opt.size());
    Collections.sort(opt);
    r=opt.get(0);
    return r; 
}
```

I obtain the following output
3
Hello
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
10

Here 3 is the value of extra[1] initially. What am I doing wrong?

The remaining code is here

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int N=in.nextInt();
    //System.out.println(N);

    in.nextLine();
    String s=in.nextLine();
    char[] S=new char[N];
    S=s.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if (S[i]=='A')
            S[i]='a';
        else if (S[i]=='C')
            S[i]='b';
            else if (S[i]=='G')
            S[i]='c';
            else if(S[i]=='T')
            S[i]='d';
    }
    //System.out.println(S[0]);
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hm=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

    hm.put('a',0);
    hm.put('b',0);
    hm.put('c',0);
    hm.put('d',0);

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        hm.put(S[i],hm.get(S[i])+1);
    }
    //System.out.println(hm.get('A'));
    int[] count=new int[4];

    count[0]=hm.get('a');
    count[1]=hm.get('b');
    count[2]=hm.get('c');
    count[3]=hm.get('d');

    //System.out.println(count[0]);

    int[] extra=new int[4];
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {          
        if (count[j]>N/4)
        {
            extra[j]=count[j]-N/4;
            //System.out.println(extra[j]);
        }  
        else
            extra[j]=0;

    }
    for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {    
        System.out.println(extra[j]);
    }
    //for (int l=0;l<4;l++)
    //System.out.println(extra[l]);
    int r=subFinder(extra,S,N);
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't copy the array. It copies only a reference.

```
    extra_tmp = extra;
```

Both `extra_tmp` and `extra` point to the same location in memory, so if you modify `extra_tmp[i]` then `extra[i]` will be modified too.

Here's an easy way to copy an array:

```
    extra_tmp = extra.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, it is given a reference. This reference holds the head of the array.

```
int[] array1 = new int[4];
int[] array2 = new int[4];

for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    array1[i] = i+1;

array2 = array1;
```

The above code will make both `array1` and `array2` pointed to the same memory address, which is the starting element of the array. `array1` and `array2` will have no difference.

Instead of doing 
`array2 = array1;` , if we do 
`array1 = array2;`

The reference to `array1` will be lost completely. The java garbage collector will free the memory allocation made for initial array1.